# Strange sorting of Greek letters using glossaries with xindy

Tags: glossaries, xindy

When TeXing the attached MWE using `xindy` for sorting, the Greek entries
are sorted between the Latin letters "R" and "S" while they are sorted after
the Latin Letters when not using `xindy`. How can this be fixed by

- either sorting them after the Latin Letters (like with `makeindex`)
- or by sorting them before the Latin Letters?

---

```
% ----- minimal example -----
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatex85}     % <-- only needed for LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
        automake,
        nomain,
        nonumberlist,
        symbols,
        % comment next `key-value` and Greek Letters are sorted 
        % after the Latin Letters
        xindy={
            codepage=utf8,
        },
            ]{glossaries-extra}
    \makeglossaries
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\newglossarystyle{symbver}{
    % change length of `\glsdescwidth'
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{8cm}

    % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
        {\begin{longtable}[l]{lp{\glsdescwidth}r}}
        {\end{longtable}}

    % No heading between groups:
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}

    % Set the table’s header:
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}

    \renewcommand*{\glsresetentrylist}{}

    % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \tabularnewline %                           start with empty row
        \rlap{%
            \glsentryitem{##1}%                     Entry number if required
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%  Name
        }
        \tabularnewline %                           end of row
    }

    % Similarly for sub-entries (no sub-entry numbers):
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        % ignoring first argument (sub-level)
        \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}%      Name
        & \glossentrydesc{##2}%                     Description
        & \glossentrysymbol{##2}%                   Unit
        \tabularnewline %                           end of row
    }

    % Nothing between groups:
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
}
\newglossaryentry{subscripts}{
    type=symbols,
    name={\textbf{Subscripts}},
    description={\nopostdesc},
    sort=d,
}
\newglossaryentry{symb:sub:alpha}{
    type=symbols,
    name=$\alpha$,
    description={entry},
    symbol={},
    sort=α:entry,
    parent=subscripts,
}
\newglossaryentry{symb:sub:omega}{
    type=symbols,
    name=$\omega$,
    description={exit},
    symbol={},
    sort=ω:exit,
    parent=subscripts,
}
\newglossaryentry{symb:sub:relative}{
    type=symbols,
    name=rel,
    description={relative},
    symbol={},
    sort=r:relative,
    parent=subscripts,
}
\newglossaryentry{symb:sub:saturation}{
    type=symbols,
    name=sat,
    description={saturation},
    symbol={},
    sort=s:saturation,
    parent=subscripts,
}
\begin{document}
        \glsaddall[types={symbols}]
    \printsymbols[
        style=symbver,
    ]
\end{document}
% ---------------------------
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a problem with the way `xindy` sorts sub-entries. It isn't specific to the `glossaries` package.

### Analysis

The following is a simpler illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeindex

\newcommand*{\lettergroupDefault}[1]{\lettergroup{#1}}

\begin{document}
α\index{α}
ω\index{ω}
r\index{r}
s\index{s}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Assuming this document is called `test.tex` then:

```
lualatex test
texindy -L english -C utf8 -o test.ind test.idx
lualatex test
```

produces:

[image: image of index, greek letters appear in default group]

This is because `xindy` has been instructed to sort according to the English alphabet, which is a Latin alphabet, so the non-Latin characters are put in the "default" group because the `english` module has no rule for them.

If instead you were to do:

```
lualatex test
texindy -L greek -C utf8 -o test.ind test.idx
lualatex test
```

then the index looks like:

[image: image of index, the Latin characters are now in the "default" letter group]

Now `xindy` has been instructed to sort according to Greek alphabet, which has no rules for Latin characters, so they're put in the "default" group.

Suppose now you try:

```
lualatex test
texindy -L russian -C utf8 -o test.ind test.idx
lualatex test
```

then all the Latin and Greek characters end up in the "default" group:

[image: image of index with all entries in the default group]

This is because `xindy` has now been instructed according to the Cyrillic alphabet and has no rules for the Latin or Greek characters.

Returning to `glossaries`, here's the index example rewritten:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{α}{name={α},description={alpha}}
\newglossaryentry{ω}{name={ω},description={omega}}
\newglossaryentry{r}{name={r},description={r}}
\newglossaryentry{s}{name={s},description={s}}

\begin{document}
\gls{α}
\gls{ω}
\gls{r}
\gls{s}

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

Now:

```
lualatex test
makeglossaries test
lualatex test
```

produces:

[image: image of sample document with Greek entries in default group]

because it's using the English sorting rules.

This is fine so far, but sub-entries seem to be behaving differently. A slight adjustment to the above example illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{d}{name={d},description={parent}}
\newglossaryentry{α}{name={α},description={alpha},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{ω}{name={ω},description={omega},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{r}{name={r},description={r},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{s}{name={s},description={s},parent=d}

\begin{document}
\gls{α}
\gls{ω}
\gls{r}
\gls{s}

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

This results in the strange ordering you noticed. I don't know why it puts the `r` entry before the Greek letters within the sub-entries, but it behaves as expected if I switch the language back to Greek:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[xindy={language=greek,glsnumbers=false}]{glossaries}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{d}{name={d},description={parent}}
\newglossaryentry{α}{name={α},description={alpha},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{ω}{name={ω},description={omega},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{r}{name={r},description={r},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{s}{name={s},description={s},parent=d}

\begin{document}
\gls{α}
\gls{ω}
\gls{r}
\gls{s}

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document with Latin entries before Greek]

So for some reason, the `english` `xindy` module seems to have a slightly different way of sorting the sub-entries. Again, this isn't specific to `glossaries` as it can be demonstrated with `\index`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeindex

\newcommand*{\lettergroupDefault}[1]{\lettergroup{#1}}

\begin{document}
α\index{d!α}
ω\index{d!ω}
r\index{d!r}
s\index{d!s}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: image of index]

The problem persists even if I define a letter group for the Greek characters:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: xindy: {language: english, codepage: utf8, modules: [basename, texindy]}
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeindex

\newcommand*{\lettergroupDefault}[1]{\lettergroup{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
(define-letter-group "Greek"
   :prefixes ("α" "ω")
   :after "Z")
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
1\index{d!1}
+\index{d!+}
α\index{d!α}
a\index{d!a}
z\index{d!z}
ω\index{d!ω}
r\index{d!r}
s\index{d!s}
1\index{1}
+\index{+}
a\index{a}
r\index{r}
s\index{s}
z\index{z}
α\index{α}
ω\index{ω}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of index]

The main (top) level entries have been correctly sorted, but not the sub-entries.

### Recommendation

I think the simplest solution is to either use a number instead of the Greek letters in the sort key (`1` for `α` etc) or use a prefix that is sorted correctly (such as `+`). For example:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: xindy: {language: english, codepage: utf8, modules: [texindy]}
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeindex

\newcommand*{\lettergroupDefault}[1]{\lettergroup{#1}}

\begin{document}

α\index{d!+α@α}
a\index{d!a}
z\index{d!z}
ω\index{d!+ω@ω}
r\index{d!r}
s\index{d!s}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: image of index with Greek letters first]

Translating this back to `glossaries`:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{d}{name={d},description={parent}}
\newglossaryentry{α}{name={α},sort={+α},description={alpha},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{ω}{name={ω},sort={+ω},description={omega},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{r}{name={r},description={r},parent=d}
\newglossaryentry{s}{name={s},description={s},parent=d}

\begin{document}
\gls{α}
\gls{ω}
\gls{r}
\gls{s}

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossary with Greek letters first]

Comment: +1: Very elaborate! In short, the problem is not solved? Right?