# Sort greek and latin letters in one symbol glossary

Tags: glossaries, unicode, xindy

I am writing my PhD thesis and create a list of symbols with glossaries and xindy. Here, latin and greek letters are used. The problem is the correct sorting with xindy. If I use english for sorting, all greek letters are put in the first group (I assume *default*) and the latin letters are sorted fine. If I set the language to greek, the latin letters are in the *default* group and the greek is sorted fine.

The problem now is, that the *default* group is sorted according to ascii code (I assume the greek is sorted by unicode?) and not alphabetically. This results in a sorting of A-Z and then a-z, instead of AaBb and so on, same for the default greek sorting, Α-Ω and then α-ω.

The image below shows both variants, with greek sorting on the left and latin sorting on the right.

I know there is the possibility to set the sorting keys manually, but then there is still no group skip between for the different letters.

Is there a way to combine the sortings for latin and greek, so that the latin characters appear first and then the greek, both in alphabetical order? I am also fine with two lists of symbols, one for latin and one for greek, but this requires two different xindy languages, which I yet did not figure out.

Cheers
Niklas

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf} % to show unicode symbols
%Greek:
\usepackage[xindy={language={greek}}, symbols,toc=false,nopostdot,nomain]{glossaries} % indices
\GlsSetXdyFirstLetterAfterDigits{Α}%% This is capital αlpha
%GreekEnd

%English
%\usepackage[xindy, symbols,toc=false,nopostdot,nomain]{glossaries} % indices
%EnglishEnd


\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{sym:A1}{type = symbols, name = Ψ, description = {test}}
\newglossaryentry{sym:a1}{type = symbols, name = ψ, description = {test}}
\newglossaryentry{sym:B1}{type = symbols, name = Δ, description = {test}}
\newglossaryentry{sym:b1}{type = symbols, name = δ, description = {test}}

\newglossaryentry{sym:A2}{type = symbols, name = A, description = {test}}
\newglossaryentry{sym:a2}{type = symbols, name = a, description = {test}}
\newglossaryentry{sym:B2}{type = symbols, name = B, description = {test}}
\newglossaryentry{sym:b2}{type = symbols, name = b, description = {test}}


\begin{document}
    \printglossary
    \glsaddall
\end{document}
```

[image: List of Symbols in greek and latin order]

Possible dublicate or similar questions, but this refers to greek letters sorted in between latin letters and subentries:
[Strange sorting of Greek letters using glossaries with xindy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312768/strange-sorting-of-greek-letters-using-glossaries-with-xindy)